# Как получить file_id документа aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram

У меня проблема с касаемо фреймворка aiogram. Я знаю, как получить file_id других типов сообщений, но не знаю, как получить file_id отправленного документа.

Код для получения ID видео:

````py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["video"])
async def video_file_id(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ваше id video")
    await message.answer(message.video.file_id)```
````

Код для получения ID фото:

````py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def photo_file_id(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ваше id photo")
    await message.answer(message.photo[2].file_id)```
````

Код для получения ID аудио:

````
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["audio"])
async def audio_file_id(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ваше id audio")
    await message.answer(message.audio.file_id)```
````

Код для получения ID стикера:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["sticker"])
async def sticker_file_id(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ваше id stiker")
    await message.answer(message.sticker.file_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто, так же, как Вы и получаете ID для других типов:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["document"])
async def sticker_file_id(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f"ID документа {message.document.file_id}")
```